# How do I remove flickering from a moving object?

Tags: c#, winforms, flicker

I've been at this for a few weeks... boiled down to its simplest component, I want to move one single circle from the left side of the screen to the right side in a SMOOTH motion, without any flickering.

Here's my code:  I instantiated a timer (timer1) and enabled in in the form's properties window and have tried values from 1-100.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int _y;
        private int _x;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _x = 0;
            _y = 200;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, _x, _y, 30, 30);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _x += 1;
            Invalidate();  //ie: redraw
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use double buffering?

Comment: That shouldn't flicker all that much.  You can add `e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;` to your paint method to make the circle a bit smoother looking.  Not sure what your complaint is otherwise.  If you are looking for game quality smoothness, you are using the wrong technology.

Comment: Flicker goes away with this=doublebuffered; but the movement will always be jumpy because there is no synch'ing with the display. Maybe using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmiller/archive/2005/05/05/415008.aspx) will help, but I haven't tried yet..

Comment: Consider using a [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to track the actual time elapsed, then compute _x based on elapsed time inside Paint rather than incrementing it in the timer.  You can then just have your Timer call Invalidate.  This still won't be perfectly smooth, but it's a lot better than the Timer callback stutter.

Answer (score 2):

Timers are discrete so there will always be some lag or stutter.

I wouldn't do this sort of animation with WinForms when WPF has animation (or in general transformation of objects) built in. The following XAML animates the red dot from (0,200) to (350,200) within 5 seconds in a smooth animation.

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="AnimationPath">
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigure>
                    <LineSegment Point="0,200" />
                    <LineSegment Point="350,200" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Ellipse Canvas.Top="200" Width="30" Height="30" Fill="Red">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslation" />
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <Ellipse.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath
                            Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslation"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                            PathGeometry="{StaticResource AnimationPath}"
                            Source="X"
                            Duration="0:0:5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Ellipse.Triggers>
    </Ellipse>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks!  'Will try this. Since i have never used QPF / XAML, I need to figure out where to paste this code :)....

Comment: @EdLandau You'll need to create a WPF project, then paste the XAML into the XAML editor that will show up. WPF and its way of programming does differ from WinForms programming a bit, though.

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME.   THANKS.    Now I have a path I can learn with light at the end of the tunnel.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: quick question: I want this to stretch to however big the window is so I put a <grid> as a parent to the <canvas> and made the canvas "stretch horizontally"... it works... but  is there a way for the value of the ending LineSegment "X" to be Canvas.width (to is goes to the end of the window)?

Comment: UN*#&$^#@Believable.     Smooth path when run from Visual Studio.  I published it. I installed it on the same machine and ran.   It is jerky.   Unbelievable.   I created smooth motion on a Mac using Motion5, exported to MP4 and it is jerky on a PC.    Are PCs that erratic ?!?!?